# Dynamic variable creation, why is that even possible?

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering why this behavior is even possible in PHP:

```
class Quick {
    public function add_variable($key,$value) {
        $this->some[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function get_variable($key) {
        return (isset($this->some[$key]))?$this->some[$key]:null;
    }
 }

 $Quick = new Quick();
 $Quick->add_variable("test1", 20);
 var_dump($Quick->get_variable("test1"));

 // Output: int(20)
```

I had some problems with that behavior and I was wondering why is it possible? what are the uses of this.

I know that in PHP varibles don't have to be declared, not even arrays and that: `$tar["key"] = "some";` is completely fine. 
But when using Objects we are declaring those variables and their access permissions.
What happens here? its public clearly... I'm a bit confused. any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because it was designed that way? And dynamically defined properties will always be public.

What uses? One example would be data models, where a property can be defined for every column dynamically, without needing to define every column in advance.

Note that you're only creating a property `some` as an array, nothing clever with `test1` which is simply an associative array element; and that your `add_variable()` and `get_variable()` methods could be implemented using magic `__get()` and `__set()`

Answer (score 0):

Being able to dynamically create associative arrays is useful when you want to index your data for fast retrieval. The example below creates an indexed array to cache the results of a resource-expensive function.

```
class Quick {
    public function add_variable($key,$value) {
        $this->some[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function get_variable($key) {
        return (isset($this->some[$key]))?$this->some[$key]:null;
    }
    public expensive_calculation($key) {
        //if the results exist in cache, return from cache
        $result = $this->get_variable($key);
        if(!is_null($result)) {
            return $result;
        }

        //do expensive calculation & store in $result
        $this->add_variable($key,$result);
        return $result;
    }    
 }
```